# How to disable automatic stage for a specific file in Git

Tags: git, staging, git-commit, autocommit

I have a file that I want it to be part of the repository but I don't want to commit its changes every time I run the `commit -a` command I normally use, but only when I manually add it to the staging area.

Is it possible with Git?

For the sake of clarity, it's a binary "output" file (a spreadsheet) that contains also some logic on how to handle the data, so I want to commit it only when I change its logic/structure and not the stored data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you really shouldn't be using `git commit -a` all the time, but rather commit incremental changes with `git add -p; git commit -v`.

However, if you still wish to go ahead, you need to do `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`, and then when you want to commit that file, do `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`.

Ref: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html